# Pyshark : Unable to get multiple Object Type values in Wireshark for BACAPP Layer

Tags: python, wireshark, tshark, pyshark

[Wireshark Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPyd0.png)

Need to get all the Object Type values as seen in the image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the image it looks like you need to dissect your BACAPP packet to the format shown.
Wireshark should have an inbuilt dissector to decode the packet, [dissector code](https://github.com/boundary/wireshark/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-bacapp.c)

Follow [this](https://www.sewio.net/open-sniffer/develop/how-to-compile-your-wireshark-dissector/) page for plugin installation.